# Get value from language specific resource file without changing the site language

Tags: asp.net, resources, cultureinfo, currentculture

I have several resource files, e.g.

default.aspx.resx, default.aspx.nl.resx, default.aspx.en.resx

Now when I'm on the Dutch domain the default.aspx.nl.resx is loaded.
But now I want to access the value from default.aspx.en.resx and get the English value belonging to name "title".

I can now achieve this by changing the current culture server-side, access the value and then change it back, like so:

```
Dim culture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en")
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture
Dim title as String = GetLocalResourceObject("title")
culture = New CultureInfo("nl")
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture
```

But is there a better/faster way? Preferably without have to change the culture for the current thread, so I can just define which resource file I want to access and in which language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add in parameter your targe culture

```
GetLocalResourceObject("title","YourCulture");
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms149953.aspx

Comment: Thank you...could you provide a sample on how to use it? I don't see any examples on the page you supplied. Thanks again!

Comment: And I tried your suggestion: GetLocalResourceObject("title", "en"), but that doesn't work. I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 btw

Comment: try with GetLocalResourceObject("title", "en-EN")

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that I'm only passing 2 parameters...I get the error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetLocalResourceObject' accepts this number of arguments.
But I don't know how else to call it and then access the returned value.

Comment: Ah, apparently I didn't. I now changed it to: lblStatus.Text = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/freemediadetails.aspx.nl.resx", "backtosearchresults").ToString

But then I get this error:
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "freemediadetails.aspx.nl.resx.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_LocalResources.root._j2bta_i" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

But this file indeed doesn't exist: freemediadetails.aspx.nl.resx.resources

Comment: Ah, this works: HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/freemediadetails.aspx", "backtosearchresults", New CultureInfo("nl")).ToString

Answer (score 3):

Edit: (Sorry I didn't know that you wanted another method different from this, but this was the only way that I managed to do:)

I managed to do this by doing:

```
var userLanguage = "en-US";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(userLanguage);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(userLanguage);

HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyAppResource", "KeyThatIWantToGet");
```

Where MyAppResource is how your .resx file is named and KeyThatIWantToGet explains itself.

Answer (score 1):

When not using the HttpContext (general .NET applications) I use the following helper:

```
/// <summary>
/// Disposable class that lets us assume a specific culture while executing 
/// a certain block of code. You'd typically use it like this:
/// 
/// using (new CultureContext("de"))
/// {
///     // Will return the German translation of "Please click here"
///     string text = SharedResource.Please_click_here;
/// }
/// </summary>
public class CultureContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _previousCulture;
    private readonly CultureInfo _previousUiCulture;

    public CultureContext(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Save off the previous culture (we'll restore this on disposal)
        _previousCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        _previousUiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }

    public CultureContext(string cultureCode)
        : this(new CultureInfo(cultureCode))
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Syntactic sugar so that we can switch to a culture context as follows:
    /// 
    /// using (CultureContext.For("de"))
    /// {
    ///     // Will return the German translation of "Please click here"
    ///     string text = SharedResource.Please_click_here;
    /// }
    /// </summary>
    public static CultureContext For(string cultureCode)
    {
        return new CultureContext(cultureCode);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Restore the culture settings that were in place before switching
        // to this context
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _previousCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _previousUiCulture;
    }
}
```